# Only show the back of the live tile in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there possible to only show the back of the tile when pinned to start? I think the back gives me more freedom, with the "Content" setting, so I would like to only use the back, and not the front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But what you can do, is to create a custom live tile background-image, which allows you to have more content on it.

I've [written a guide on how to do exactly that](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-live-tile-directly-o)